# "the Package.resolved file is most likely severely out-of-date and is preventing correct resolution"

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm getting the following error when trying to build. It shows up as the only item in the build log, too.

[image: Package Loading: the Package.resolved file is most likely severely out-of-date and is preventing correct resolution; delete the resolved file and try again]

Here are the packages I'm using:

[image: 5 Swift packages listed in the project settings: SimpleLogging, OptionalTools, FunctionTools, SpecialString, and Swift-TODO. The first 3 are URLs to git files (they end in .git), and the last 2 are URLs to the repos themselves (they end in a slash).][image: The same 5 packages as above, but listed in the sidebar, proving they were resolved successfully.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, it turned out that, even though Xcode was able to resolve and clone these packages, it didn't like that 2 of them pointed to the GitHub repo page, rather than the git file version.

Changing them so they're all `.git` URLs fixed it:

[image: The same project package list as above, but none end in a slash; all end in .git]